# I am unable to remove browser hijacker

Tags: browser, malware

I have noticed many times after few weeks my browser's search engine gets changed to some *conduict* search engine. But today i found a reason I found some suspicious third party software and when i googled it got confirmed that it was the reason

> Name of that file is NvSTECH toolbar

But now my problem is when i try to uninstall it in `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` this location nothing happens (*I tried many times*) i did a full PC scan with windows defender but it couldn't find it so i don't know what is path to that `NvSTECH toolbar` file(*or program*) so i can't even delete it.

If possible tell a way other than downloading any Anti adware

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Try looking for 'Search Protect'

Comment: [Remove NvSTECH Toolbar and NvSTECH Customized Web Search](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/nvstech-toolbar-removal/)

Comment: @DavidPostill i read that whole stuff but it includes third party software

Comment: "third party software" safe to use and the only way to get rid of this stuff.

Comment: I have *malwarebytes* but i have noticed that it identifies all stuff but when i remove them, they don't get removed rather i find them in there place

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cleaned the default start page of the browser (and possible secondary tabs), it is most likely there is an application that auto-re-adds that thing to the browser at each restart or every time the browser starts (if it's in the memory). Best thing would be to get a startup control application so you can see when the app that loads that addon is launched from and remove the entry. You will also have to end task that respawner app before anything else can be cleaned up. It may launch from a file, from the registry or as parameter of another exe application. If you don't know very well all possible startup locations, get something that displays them all.